# Найти координаты определённого текста на картинке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо найти координаты текста, допустим "Test" на картинке в формате PNG или JPG. Пробовал делать поиск картинки на экране через pyautogui, но распознавание слишком точное. Если изменить пару пикселей в картинке, то скрипт не находит координаты

Comment: Люди по данному вопросу научные работы пишут, диссертации защищают, коммерческие компании создают. А Вам вот вынь да положь. И чтоб хорошо работало...

Comment: Посмотрите проекты **Pyllow** и **PyTesseract**, **Keras** и **TensorFlow**. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279667/scrapy-simple-captcha-solving-example), [здесь](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-solve-simple-captchas-using-python-tesseract/), [здесь](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/how-to-break-a-captcha-system-in-15-minutes-with-machine-learning-dbebb035a710)